Xamarin ios error on closing app: unexpected start state
I have a xamarin app which works fine in ios devices. But when I move to another app using app switcher, it crashes. Here's the error log:
2024-06-22 22:46:00.276 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[1496:141395] *** Assertion failure in void _UIApplicationDrainManagedAutoreleasePool(void)(), UIApplication+AutoreleasePool.m:171
2024-06-22 22:46:00.282 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[1496:141395] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unexpected start state'
Foundation.MonoTouchException: 'Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: unexpected start state
